# What is forward proxy and reverse proxy?

Tags: proxy

So I've just been learning about proxy and I had a bit of confusion about both forward proxy and reverse proxy. So I'm gonna go through my assumption and please correct me if I'm wrong

**Forward Proxy**

forward proxy is a proxy that runs in a private network it's internal meaning that it runs in your computer offline it stands in between you and the internet
the process goes like `computer ==> forward proxy ==> internet ==> web application`

**Reverse Proxy**

reverse proxy is a proxy that runs entirely online. If forward proxy was provided by your computer
Reverse proxy is usually provided by your ISP.
and the process goes like `computer ==> internet ==> reverse proxy ==> web application`

**NOTE** that every thing that I've typed regarding proxy is an assumption

Comment: Your assumption of a reverse proxy isn't quite right. Quoting [from CloudFlare's blog](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/): 

`A forward proxy sits in front of a client and ensures that no origin server ever communicates directly with that specific client. On the other hand, a reverse proxy sits in front of an origin server and ensures that no client ever communicates directly with that origin server`